# Using two cell values to extract a value from a table where the values are in between each row value and column value

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, extract, vlookup

| Litres/Milage | 1.2 | 1.5 | 1.501 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1500 | 41.8 | 43.4 | 51.8 |
| 5500 | 72.64 | 79.18 | 90.63 |
| 25000 | 31.78 | 31.79 | 39.22 |
| 25001 | 20.56 | 23.85 | 25.87 |

on the table above I want to create formular to use data from that table where I have litre(x axis) and miles y (axis).

I have two cells(litres and Milage) where there is value entered and when those values are entered it will return the answer from the table For EG
if i have 1.4 litres and 5600 miles it should return a value of 79.18
if the same milage was done with litre 0f 1.6 it would return a value of 90.63

I have tried doing index with matches but that doesn't take into account value amounts between rows or column headers

I tried using if statements. I'm lost for next stages
Index(,Match,match) was the formular i tried before
The table is on sperate sheet to the two values being used

Comment: If you're using matches make sure to use non-exact matches so it finds the next closest which is likely why it's not looking at the figures in between the values.

Comment: Your values should be the lower end of the span not the max.  So the liter titles should be {0,1.201,1.501} respectively Then use: `=INDEX(B2:D5,MATCH(5600,A2:A5),MATCH(1.4,B1:D1))`

Comment: Scott your answer help get the solution i was looking for fromatting seamed to be incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Just for variety, if what OP wants is the *nearest* match, you could try comparing to the average of each adjacent pair of lookup values (mileage or litres):

```
=LET(litres,B$1:D$1,
mileage,A$2:A$5,
values,B$2:D$5,
lmap,(litres+HSTACK(DROP(litres,,1),9^9))/2,
mmap,(mileage+VSTACK(DROP(mileage,1),9^9))/2,
XLOOKUP(F2,lmap,XLOOKUP(G2,mmap,values,,1),,1))
```

[image]

---

My formula for 'up to and including' each limit would be

```
=LET(litres,B$1:D$1,
mileage,A$2:A$5,
values,B$2:D$5,
lmap,HSTACK(DROP(litres,,-1),9^9),
mmap,VSTACK(DROP(mileage,-1),9^9),
XLOOKUP(J3,lmap,XLOOKUP(K3,mmap,values,,1),,1))
```

As shown by @Scott Craner you can vary the limits slightly to make it inclusive or non-inclusive, or alternatively to make it match up to but not including the limits:

```
=LET(litres,B$1:D$1,
mileage,A$2:A$5,
values,B$2:D$5,
lmap,HSTACK(0,DROP(litres,,-1)),
mmap,VSTACK(0,DROP(mileage,-1)),
XLOOKUP(J3,lmap,XLOOKUP(K3,mmap,values,,-1),,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: That Answer has gotten me 90% there  and i can only thank you 

from formula ive gotten very close so for eg when litres is 1.6 and the milage goes above 1500 the value should be 51.8 and that should be the value until the  milage reaches 5500 the value from 5500 to 25000 miles should be39.22 and anything over 25000 ie 25001 should be 25.87
The forumla is calculate the milage rate(Value) base on the engine size(Litre) and milage 
Thanks again